# Como resuelvo error de sintaxis en sentecia Mysql (python)

Tags: python

Estoy intentando insertar un registro en una tabla llamada direccion_1
pero me da error en la linea 6 cursor.execute(sql, ("dato 1", "dato 2", "dato 3")) - indicandome lo siguiente:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''direccion_1' ('categoria',
>   'nombre', 'direccion') VALUES('dato 1', 'dato 2', 'd' at line 1")

no logro detectar la falla el codigo es este:

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',db='direcciones')
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "INSERT INTO 'direccion_1' ('categoria', 'nombre', 'direccion') VALUES(%s, %s, %s) "
        cursor.execute(sql, ("dato 1", "dato 2", "dato 3"))
        connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
    print("Feliz termino")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nombre de tu tabla en la sentencia SQL, no debe de ir entre comillas, (como lo muestra un ejemplo de [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp))

EDIT: Como mencionan en los comentarios, tampoco van entre comillas el nombre de las columnas

Tu query debería de ser:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO direccion_1 (categoria, nombre, direccion) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, probé asi pero me sigue dando el mismo error en la siguiente linea. cursor.execute(sql, ("dato 1", "dato 2", "dato 3"))

Comment: Es exactamente el mismo error? quiero decir, igual tiene la parte que dice `to use near 'direccion_1'`?

Comment: Las comillas simples en los nombres de columna, también pueden obviarse.

Comment: es el mismo error :syntax to use near ''categoria', 'nombre', 'direccion') VALUES('dato 1', 'dato 2', 'dato 3')' at line 1"), aunque modifique el codigo asignado los valores dato 1 2 y e a una variable llamada val:   val =("dato 1", "dato 2", "dato 3")  y da error en esta linea: cursor.execute(sql, val)

Comment: elimine las comillas simples y funciono. mil gracias y una v